# IdFTP Get Error File Not Found

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

I created a program to get a file from FTP servers every 5 seconds.

(I'm using Delphi 7)

To do this I did an IdFTP array.

Everything looks like OK, but when the file doesn't exist, the application crashes.

Message: Project FTPGETFIle.exe raised exception class EldProtocolReplyError with message 'File not found'

Creating array from INI file:

```
      IFTP[i] := TIdFTP.Create(nil);
      IFTP[i].Host := IniFile.hostn[i];
      IFTP[i].Username := IniFile.usern;
      IFTP[i].Password := IniFile.password;
      IFTP[i].Port := IniFile.FTPPort;
      IFTP[i].OnConnected := FTPConnect;
      IFTP[i].OnDisconnected := FTPDisconnect;
      IFTP[i].OnStatus := FTPStatus;
      IFTP[i].Passive := True;
```

Get file timer:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to IniFile.nftp do
  begin
    if pingIP(IniFile.hostn[i]) then
    begin
      if IFTP[i].Connected then
      begin
        writelog ('Get file '+IniFile.FTPFile[i]+' and save to '+IniFile.OutputF[i]);
        try
          IFTP[i].Get (IniFile.FTPFile[i],IniFile.OutputF[i],true, false);
        except
          on E:EIdFileNotFound do
            writelog(E.Message);
          on E:EIdProtocolReplyError do
            writelog(E.Message);
          on E:Exception do
            writelog(e.Message);
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
      writelog(IniFile.hostn[i]+' is not recheable!');
  end;
end;
```

Can someone help me to treat this "file not found"?

Comment: You are getting an error from the FTP server. It is telling you that the path/filename you have requested doesn't exist on the server. Double-check your `IniFile.FTPFile[i]` value. Is it just a filename by itself? Or is it a relative path or an absolute path? Also, `EIdFileNotFound` is not an Indy exception that `TIdFTP` would raise.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand why you wish to acquire a file via FTP every 5 seconds. It seems to me this type of network activity could potentially get your IP blocked, if said FTP Server is a third-party. On the other hand, if you have full control over the server, and don't necessarily need FTP in particular, I'd highly advise against it. FTP shouldn't be used in such a nature these days. HTTP is a more appropriate method of acquiring a file, especially if you need it every 5 seconds. Keep in mind that FTP was invented long before HTTP was.

Comment: If FTP is not a requirement, you should *seriously* seek another solution. Please read here, for example: https://www.cloudfastpath.com/blog/why-is-ftp-still-so-ubiquitous/ An article which I myself *could* have potentially written, given it matches precisely how I and many others view FTP, as well as writing style. But not me. Just for perspective, it's not just me telling you.

Comment: Jerry, This is an only possible connection with an industrial robot. I have to get robot status. My question is: if someone change INI File with filename that doesn't exist? The application will stops. I don't know why, but looks like that TRY EXCEPT is not working.

Comment: Are you running your app in debug mode? Because in debug mode, by default, you will *always* see exceptions, even if they're handled.When you're not in debug mode, it shouldn't show any message, and in either situation, it shouldn't crash your entire app as you describe.

Comment: I disabled debug mode at    Tools>Debugger Options and unchecked: Integrated debugging and the exceptions are working.... thank you